# Custom favicon in NEXT.JS

Tags: frontend, next.js14

I am using a custom file `Heading.tsx` for **"title and metadata"** and I want to add a custom favicon in my next.js **v14** app. Please help me!!. Here is the code :

```js
import React, {FC} from "react";
interface HeadProps{
    title: string;
    description: string;
    keywords: string;
}

// Creating page
const Heading:FC<HeadProps> = ({title, description, keywords}) => {
    return(
        <>
            <title>{title}</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            <meta name="description" content={description} />
            <meta name="keywords" content={keywords} />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../public/assets/favicon.ico" />
        </>
    );
}
export default Heading;
```

This method didn't work:

Answer (score 0):

Update your Heading component to reference the custom favicon file using the next/head component:

```html
import Head from 'next/head';
import React, { FC } from 'react';

interface HeadProps {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  keywords: string;
}

const Heading: FC<HeadProps> = ({ title, description, keywords }) => {
  return (
    <Head>
      <title>{title}</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <meta name="description" content={description} />
      <meta name="keywords" content={keywords} />
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" /> // give your path
    </Head>
  );
};

export default Heading;
```